# Image is animated when the background position is changed with Skrollr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, skrollr

I'm trying to do a div that change the background image every X px that is scrolled.
Initially I tried with change background-image(also with a sprite and background position) but it give me a "flickering" effect.
You Can see it here: https://whispering-ocean-4900.herokuapp.com/ (here the example isn't done with sprite but the effect is the same).

Then I tried to load only one time the sprite and change only background-position.
It works fine if I use something like: center left; top left etc...
If I use px, for example `background-position: 50px 0px;` It animates the image (moving it).
You can see it here: http://bit.ly/1h4FOVR

I have done this with:

```
<div 
  style="
    width: 600px; 
    height: 1000px; 
    position: static; 
    background: url('./Testapp_files/merry1.png'); 
    background-position: 50px 0px;
  " 
  data-0="background-position: 150px 0px;" 
  data-150="background-position:500px 0px;" 
  data-250="background-position: 25px 0px;" 
  data-350="background-position: 0px 0px;" 
  class="skrollable skrollable-between"></div>
```

Instead if I do it like this (but I can't do for a real sprite):

```
<div 
  style="
    width: 600px; 
    height: 1000px; 
    position: static; 
    background: url('file:///Users/ste/Downloads/Archivio/Testapp_files/m./Testapp_files/merry1.jpg'); 
    background-position: top left;
  " 
  data-0="background-position: top right;"  
  data-150="background-position: center left;" 
  data-250="background-position: top right;" 
  data-350="background-position: top left;" 
  class="skrollable skrollable-between"></div>
```

All works fine...what is the difference ? How I can fix ??

The problem of flickering is very hard to fix(reading on the internet, is a bug/problem of webkit), but why when I change the background-position(this will be a great workaround) do this strange thing ?

Thank You very Much.

Answer (score 1):

sorry I know this is from 6 months ago...

The problem with the first code is that it is using numbers (for the px position) and skrollr interpolates every number it finds. Therefore it animates the change between the numbers instead of just jumping from one to the other.

This is in the skrollr readme and easy to prevent if you don't want the change animated. You simply put an exclamation mark in front of the numbers, like so...

```
data-0="background-position: !150px 0px;"
```

Here's the info in the skrollr readme:- https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/blob/master/README.md#preventing-interpolation